# Two Objects arrays and concat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, concatenation

i have two arrays that are both connected to a scope (http get etc.):

```
$scope.allShops
```

that hold all the shop details and

```
$scope.allCds
```

that hold all the cd's

both work fine and the Ng-Repeat gives me all the output (individually) i need, i however would like to build a search that allows me to search on the cd name and on the shop name from the same search field (using a label to mention if its a shop or a cd to avoid confusion). So i came up with this:

```
$scope.allShops = [];
$scope.allCds = [];

var jointData1 = '';
var jointData2 = '';
var SearchAll = '';

    var jointData1 = $scope.allShops;
    console.info(jointData1);

    var jointData2 = $scope.allCds;
    console.info(jointData2);

    var searchAll = jointData1.concat(jointData2);
    console.info(searchAll)
```

But all the logs are empty, if i place the log inside the succes.array function it shows me the data object but placing the log with the scope outside give me nothing. How do i get the data outside the array function and able to concat the two scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console.info calls will be empty because the $http service hasn't got the data back yet.

You'd have to do this after the data is returned by using a promise (`.then()`)

Comment: is there not a way to update them, when it receives the data? Could i do this perhaps as example? "i load first the shops and display them under the searchAll, then i will load the cd's and add them to the searchAll" cds holds a lot of rows so i takes some time to load as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
        var obj3 = {};
        for (var attrname1 in obj1) {
            obj3[attrname1] = obj1[attrname1];
        }
        for (var attrname2 in obj2) { obj3[attrname2] = obj2[attrname2]; }
        return obj3;
    }
merge_options(obj1,obj2);
```

Comment: how do i implement this, what is the attrnameX?

Comment: just pass  your 2 objects to this function and the function will return the merged object

Comment: attrname1 is key name of object